# What message will send when a application is installed or uninstalled

Tags: windows, installation, backup, uninstallation

I want to backup my system Register when a application is planing to be installed or uninstalled, what message will send from installer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no proper solution for a common case.

Installer - is just a program which places your files into suitable directories and performs some additional actions, including registry manipulations.

As far as I know there no "message" for installers to be sent before or after installation.